# CATIA GetBoundary(ref iLabel) What value should iRabel parameter enter?

Tags: catia

What value should `iRabel` parameter enter?

Error message:

> The call to the COM component returned the error HRESULT E_FAIL.

Comment: There are 3 different objects which have a method GetBoundary. Of which do you speak?.  Please post some code reproducing the error.

Comment: Got the same problem, none of the 3 different objects even work.
e.g. neither Body nor Part. But my purpose is to get "Mesh" or Triangles from Catia solid, then export out to display in another platform